# Haml Text Compression

Tags: haml, erb

Okay,

I'm using haml to create a template and came across a stumble.

I normally use "<" in haml to bring all the text on one line after it preprocesses.

i.e.:

```
%p 
%img{:src => "link to image"}<
Some text
```

but when I use

```
image_tag "image name", :alt => "some text"
Some text
```

How can I the  "<" to the end of that so that the text below the image can render on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I'd consider interpolating the `image_tag` in a string with `"Some text"` on the end:

`= "#{image_tag('image_name', :alt => 'some text')} Some text"`